# Limelight Video player (Shuffle functionality)

Tags: javascript, video, flash

I figured out there is no functionality of SHUFFLE in you delve player. I am trying to implement such functionality using delve player's javascript api.  Some strange reason we are not able to get this functionality because DelvePlayer.doSetMedia function is not working as it should under onMediaComplete event. Although DelvePlayer.doSetMedia is working on button click

please see code snippet below

```
function delvePlayerCallback(playerId, eventName, data) {   

var id = "limelight_player_20758";
if (eventName == 'onPlayerLoad' && (DelvePlayer.getPlayers() == null || DelvePlayer.getPlayers().length == 0)) {
  DelvePlayer.registerPlayer(id);
}


switch (eventName) {

  case 'onMediaComplete':
        var playIndex = 0;  
        channel = DelvePlayer.doGetCurrentChannel();
        media_count = channel.mediaList.length;
        if(media_count > 1)
        {
            getRandomNum = randomFromTo(0, (media_count > 1) ? media_count - 1 : 0) ;

            //alert(getRandomNum + ' ' + channel.mediaList[getRandomNum].id + ' ' + channel.mediaList[getRandomNum].title + ' current index: ' + DelvePlayer.doGetCurrentIndex());

             //this function is not working
             DelvePlayer.doSetMedia(channel.mediaList[getRandomNum].id,true); // this function is not working

            //DelvePlayer.doPlay();
        }

    break; 

    case 'onError' :
        alert ('error');
    break;
}   }
```

Please advise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolved this issue after consult to limelight network team

they suggested to put slight delay on call to doSetMedia()

here is code snippet

```
switch (eventName) 
{ 

case 'onMediaComplete': 

t=setTimeout("DelvePlayer.doSetMedia('90ab7c3144c94337a8b94cf2c5c56407',true)",500);
break ;

}
```

thanks to Huw Morgan at LimeLight

cheers

Answer (score 0):

are servers working?
check the link. maybe it is your answer too.

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/7211/streaming-with-limelight

Comment: thanks viaria for your time. This is not a case with my query.